# Determine which factors are significant, using machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am very inexperienced when it comes to machine learning, but I would like to learn and in order to improve my skills I am currently trying to apply the things I have learned on one of my own research data sets.

I have a dataset with 77 rows and 308 columns. Every row correspondents to a sample. 305 out of the 308 columns give information about concentrations, one column tells whether the column belongs to group A,B,C or D, one column tells whether it is an X or Y sample and one column tells you eventually whether the output is successful or not. I would like to determine which concentrations significantly impact the output, taking into account the variation between the groups and sample types. I have tried multiple things (feature selection, classification, etc.) but so far I do not get the desired output

My question is therefore whether people have suggestions/tips/ideas about how I could tackle this problem, taking into account that the dataset is relatively small and that only 15 out the 77 samples have 'not successful' as output?

Comment: the fact that you're not getting desired output might because of something different than features you have used. but generally for feature selection you can do PCA, filter based feature selection, whitening transforms and etc. please note that feature selection and classification are different things. you have a classification problem in which you're using feature selection.

Comment: You'll need some dimensionality reduction technique here with such few samples

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the correlation and sort it. After sorting take top 10-15 categories/features.